# Не работают виджеты django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Изучаю понемногу джанго
Хочу сделать выбор в поле чекбоксами.Но на сайте поля даже не появляются(поле client step появляется).подскажите
делаю так:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import DateField, ChoiceField, MultipleChoiceField
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect, CheckboxSelectMultiple
from django.forms import widgets

# Create your models here.
class Client(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'client'
    #choices
    CLIENT_STEP_CHOICES = (
    ('F', 'first'),
    ('S', 'second'),
)
    FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (('blue', 'Blue'),
                               ('green', 'Green'),
                               ('black', 'Black'))
#fields
    client_step = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = CLIENT_STEP_CHOICES, default = 'F')

    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 1):

Поле модели не может быть forms.MultipleChoiceField, оно будет просто проигнорировано, так как это поле формы а не модели (как например models.CharField)

Один из способов реализовать множественные чекбоксы в django:

**Модели:**

```
class Color(models.Model):
    # Сделаем поле name первичным ключем, так оно попадет в value чекбокса
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)  
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        # Реализуем метод, выводящий title, он будет подставлен в label чекбокса
        return self.title


class Client(models.Model):
    ...
    client_step = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CLIENT_STEP_CHOICES, default='F')
    favorite_colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
```

**Форма:**

```
from django import forms

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_step', 'favorite_colors')
        widgets = {
            # Укажем для поля favorite_colors нужный нам виджет
            'favorite_colors': forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

Цвета теперь будут хранится в модели Color, вам необходимо создать соответсвующие записи.